# Custom header shows two or three or more images

Tags: headers, custom-header

Is there is a way to make the custom header to show more than one image in a random show without duplicate images.

I tried something like this:

```
<?php $header_image = get_header_image();
    if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" />
                </li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" />

                </li>
            </ul>
            </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

But dose not work - Any advice please?

Want something like this in the latest wordpress Version 3.5.1
[image]

and want to make every image change with random without duplicate

Comment: Are you talking about a slideshow? There are many plugins available for this.

Comment: No I am talking about the normal custom header in the latest wordpress Version 3.5.1